# How to align text to center in asp label

Tags: asp.net, html

I have a label in which i need to align the text to center
,I have tried this

```
 <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="ABC" style="text-align:center" Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="X-Large" CssClass="StrongText"></asp:Label>
```

But it not works..

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
<div style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; text-align: center;">
    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="ABC" Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="X-Large"
        CssClass="StrongText"></asp:Label>
</div>
```

Comment: But this also aligns the label control to the centre, as well as the text. What if you want the label left aligned, but the Text contents to be centred? Sorry had to -1

Comment: @Gregor Primar: Why this is not working: asp:Label ID="lblLogin" runat="server" Font-Size="X-Large" ForeColor="Red" Font-Bold="true" style="text-align:center"></asp:Label> When i have to align the text in center of a asp.net label ?

Comment: Place your Label inside div as in my sample and it should work. If not then check what is align settings for parent HTML object.

Answer (score 3):

If you write `text-align: center;` it will not work, try adding `display:inline-block;` to the style definition.

Answer (score 1):

Set the margin to 0; always check the parent element of any element as they inherit their css properties

Answer (score 0):

```
Use the following CSS Class to align label text center

.textAlign{
                text-align:center;
            }
```